# Convert lastKnowLocation to String or CharSequance then print out using Toast.maketext but fails

Tags: android, gps, toast

I have got GPS coordinates from Android, and I want to print out coordinates using the `toast.maketext` method. My code is like the following.

```
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener LocListener = new LocationListener(){

        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }
    };

    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, LocListener);

    Location lastKnownLocation = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    double latitude=lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
    double longtitude=lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
    CharSequence coordinate="Latitude = " + Double.toString(latitude) + "\nLongitude = " + Double.toString(longtitude);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), coordinate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

No matter coordinate is string or charSequence, the application cannot run because of misuse of `Toast.maketext`. But the Eclipse compiler never identifies this problem. How would I handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. `getLastKnownLocation()` only gives the last *cached* location. There may be no such cached location if the phone was off, for example.

In the `onLocationChanged()` callback you check if the `Location` object is `null`, if not, get the (latitude,longitude) from the `Location` object post a Toast from there.

Also, in this case it is better to use `LogCat` for debugging, you will be getting location fixes every second. Use `Log.d("WOOO", "Location received" + loc.getLatitude() + " " + loc.getLongitude());` in the `onLocationChanged()` callback.